# Bug: Blob Object creates empty PDF file

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, download, blob

I was facing an issue where I was recieving a valid PDF from a Java servlet but at the time where I created the Blob object in Javascript it wasn't being correctly created.

The data I was recieving had this aspect:
[PDF from Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfImu.png)

But the PDF file was like this:
[PDF visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWJ94.png)

This was how I was creating the PDF binary chain in Java (AEM):

```
private void streamPDF (final SlingHttpServletResponse response, final Resource pdfRes) throws IOException {
        String fileName = pdfRes.getPath().substring(pdfRes.getPath().lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

        Asset asset = pdfRes.adaptTo(Asset.class);
        final InputStream in = asset.getOriginal().getStream();

        final OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        IOUtils.copy(in, out);

        out.close();

        in.close();
    }
```

And I was reading it like this in Javascript:

```
sendServletDownload: function (title, path) {
        let url = "myurl.pdf";
        $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: 'GET',
           data: {
               path: path
           },
           success: function (data) {
               var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

               // Create an URL object for the Blob
               var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

               // Configure the download link with the Blob's URL and the filename
               var downloadLink = document.getElementById('downloadLink');
               downloadLink.href = url;

               downloadLink.download = title + '.pdf';

               // Simulate a click in the link to iniciate the download
               downloadLink.click();

               // Free the URL of the object when it's not necessary anymore
               window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
           }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log("Error: {}", errorThrown);
           },
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'arraybuffer' // Stablish responseType to 'arraybuffer'
            }
       });
    }
```

I tried to change the decode the 'data' from base64 to ArrayBuffer but it wasn't the issue.

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(data) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(data);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
        var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally could solve it!

The issue was that the responseType of the Ajax call wasn't correct.

If you are facing the same issue try to add this to your Ajax call:

```
xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer' // Stablish responseType to 'arraybuffer'
        }
```

It should look like this after put it:

```
$.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: 'GET',
       data: {
           path: path
       },
       success: function (data) {
           var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

           // Create an URL object for the Blob
           var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

           // Configure the download link with the Blob's URL and the filename
           var downloadLink = document.getElementById('downloadLink');
           downloadLink.href = url;

           downloadLink.download = title + '.pdf';

           // Simulate a click in the link to iniciate the download
           downloadLink.click();

           // Free the URL of the object when it's not necessary anymore
           window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
       }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("Error: {}", errorThrown);
       },
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer' // Stablish responseType to 'arraybuffer'
        }
   });
```